# Join three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have those three tables

```
SELECT occuId as 'Occupation Id',occuDscr as 'Occupation Description' FROM occupation_field;
+---------------+------------------------+
| Occupation Id | Occupation Description |
+---------------+------------------------+
|             1 | Software Engineer      |
|             2 | Economics              |
|             3 | Structural Engineer    |
|             4 | Legal Advisors         |
|             5 | Plumbers               |
|             6 | Social Advisors        |
|             7 | Musicians              |
+---------------+------------------------+

SELECT usrId AS 'User Id',usrName AS 'User Name',usrOccuId AS 'User Occupation Id' FROM users;
+---------+------------+--------------------+
| User Id | User Name  | User Occupation Id |
+---------+------------+--------------------+
|       2 | goodys     |                  6 |
|       5 | realmadrid |                  7 |
|       6 | petousis   |                  6 |
+---------+------------+--------------------+

SELECT pstId AS 'Post Id',pstTitle AS 'Post Title',pstOccuId AS 'Post Occupation Id' FROM job_post ORDER BY pstId;
+---------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Post Id | Post Title                                | Post Occupation Id |
+---------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|       4 | Software Engineer Recruit                 |                  1 |
|       5 | Web Developer Recruit                     |                  1 |
|       6 | Saxophonist                               |                  7 |
|       7 | Construction Company looking for plumber. |                  5 |
|       8 | Economic Analyst                          |                  2 |
|       9 | Legal Advisor                             |                  4 |
|      10 | Economic Assistant                        |                  2 |
+---------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to combine the below two tables in order to have one with the Occupation Descriptions,Post per Job and Users per Job.

```
SELECT occuDscr job,count(pstOccuId) AS 'Posts' FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field on pstOccuId = occuId GROUP BY job;
+-------------------+-------+
| job               | Posts |
+-------------------+-------+
| Economics         |     2 |
| Legal Advisors    |     1 |
| Musicians         |     1 |
| Plumbers          |     1 |
| Software Engineer |     2 |
+-------------------+-------+

SELECT occuDscr job,count(usrOccuId) AS 'Users' FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field on usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY job;
+-----------------+-------+
| job             | Users |
+-----------------+-------+
| Musicians       |     1 |
| Social Advisors |     2 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Something like this

```
    +-------------------+-------+-------+
    | job               | Posts | Users |
    +-------------------+-------+-------+
    | Economics         |     2 |     0 |
    | Legal Advisors    |     1 |     0 |
    | Musicians         |     1 |     1 |
    | Plumbers          |     1 |     0 |
    | Software Engineer |     2 |     0 |
    | Social Advisors   |     0 |     1 |
    +-------------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I essentially performed a LEFT JOIN of the `occupation_field` table against both of your queries, joining by means of the occuDscr field. Here is your new query:

```
SELECT
    oc.occuDscr job,
    IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
        FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
        ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ) postInfo
    USING (occuDscr)
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
        FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
        ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ) userInfo
    USING (occuDscr)
;
```

If the USING clause is not clear to you, here is your without the USING clause

```
SELECT
    oc.occuDscr job,
    IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
        FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
        ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ) postInfo
    ON oc.occuDscr = postInfo.occuDscr
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
        FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
        ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ) userInfo
    ON oc.occuDscr = userInfo.occuDscr
;
```

Here is your sample data loaded:

```
mysql> drop database if exists giannosfor;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> create database giannosfor;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use giannosfor
Database changed
mysql> create table occupation_field
    -> (occuId int not null auto_increment,
    -> occuDscr varchar(40),
    -> primary key (occuId));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into occupation_field (occuDscr) values
    -> ('Software Engineer'),('Economics'),('Structural Engineer'),
    -> ('Legal Advisors'),('Plumbers'),('Social Advisors'),('Musicians');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table users
    -> (usrId int not null,
    -> usrName varchar(20),
    -> usrOccuId int not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into users values
    -> (2,'goodys',6),(5,'realmadrid',7),(6,'petousis',6);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table job_post
    -> (pstId int not null,pstTitle varchar(60),
    -> pstOccuId int not null,
    -> primary key (pstId));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into job_post values
    -> ( 4,'Software Engineer Recruit',1),
    -> ( 5,'Web Developer Recruit',1),
    -> ( 6,'Saxophonist',7),
    -> ( 7,'Construction Company looking for plumber.',5),
    -> ( 8,'Economic Analyst',2),
    -> ( 9,'Legal Advisor',4),
    -> (10,'Economic Assistant',2);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from occupation_field;
+--------+---------------------+
| occuId | occuDscr            |
+--------+---------------------+
|      1 | Software Engineer   |
|      2 | Economics           |
|      3 | Structural Engineer |
|      4 | Legal Advisors      |
|      5 | Plumbers            |
|      6 | Social Advisors     |
|      7 | Musicians           |
+--------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+-------+------------+-----------+
| usrId | usrName    | usrOccuId |
+-------+------------+-----------+
|     2 | goodys     |         6 |
|     5 | realmadrid |         7 |
|     6 | petousis   |         6 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from job_post;
+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+
| pstId | pstTitle                                  | pstOccuId |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+
|     4 | Software Engineer Recruit                 |         1 |
|     5 | Web Developer Recruit                     |         1 |
|     6 | Saxophonist                               |         7 |
|     7 | Construction Company looking for plumber. |         5 |
|     8 | Economic Analyst                          |         2 |
|     9 | Legal Advisor                             |         4 |
|    10 | Economic Assistant                        |         2 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the execution of the first query

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr job,
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
    ->         FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) postInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
    ->         FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) userInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    -> ;
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| job                 | Posts | Users |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| Economics           |     2 |     0 |
| Legal Advisors      |     1 |     0 |
| Musicians           |     1 |     1 |
| Plumbers            |     1 |     0 |
| Social Advisors     |     0 |     2 |
| Software Engineer   |     2 |     0 |
| Structural Engineer |     0 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the execution of the second query

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr job,
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
    ->         FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) postInfo
    ->     ON oc.occuDscr = postInfo.occuDscr
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
    ->         FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) userInfo
    ->     ON oc.occuDscr = userInfo.occuDscr
    -> ;
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| job                 | Posts | Users |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| Economics           |     2 |     0 |
| Legal Advisors      |     1 |     0 |
| Musicians           |     1 |     1 |
| Plumbers            |     1 |     0 |
| Social Advisors     |     0 |     2 |
| Software Engineer   |     2 |     0 |
| Structural Engineer |     0 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-01-11 11:50 EDT**

To remove Jobs with no Posts, change the first LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr job,
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    ->     INNER JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
    ->         FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) postInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
    ->         FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) userInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    -> ;
+-------------------+-------+-------+
| job               | Posts | Users |
+-------------------+-------+-------+
| Economics         |     2 |     0 |
| Legal Advisors    |     1 |     0 |
| Musicians         |     1 |     1 |
| Plumbers          |     1 |     0 |
| Software Engineer |     2 |     0 |
+-------------------+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

To remove Jobs with no Users, change the second LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr job,
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
    ->         FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) postInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    ->     INNER JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
    ->         FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) userInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    -> ;
+-----------------+-------+-------+
| job             | Posts | Users |
+-----------------+-------+-------+
| Musicians       |     1 |     1 |
| Social Advisors |     0 |     2 |
+-----------------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

To remove Jobs with no Users or no Posts, change the both LEFT JOINs into INNER JOINs:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr job,
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    ->     INNER JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
    ->         FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) postInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    ->     INNER JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
    ->         FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) userInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    -> ;
+-----------+-------+-------+
| job       | Posts | Users |
+-----------+-------+-------+
| Musicians |     1 |     1 |
+-----------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### **UPDATE 2012-01-11 12:03 EDT**

To remove Jobs with no Post or Users, add a WHERE clause to check if either cound is greater than zero:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr job,
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0) Posts,
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0) Users
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT * FROM occupation_field ORDER BY occuDscr) oc
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(pstOccuId) AS 'PostCount'
    ->         FROM job_post INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON pstOccuId = OccuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) postInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT occuDscr,COUNT(usrOccuId) AS 'UserCount'
    ->         FROM users INNER JOIN occupation_field
    ->         ON usrOccuId = occuId GROUP BY occuDscr
    ->     ) userInfo
    ->     USING (occuDscr)
    -> WHERE
    ->     IFNULL(postInfo.PostCount,0)>0 OR
    ->     IFNULL(userInfo.UserCount,0)>0
    -> ;
+-------------------+-------+-------+
| job               | Posts | Users |
+-------------------+-------+-------+
| Economics         |     2 |     0 |
| Legal Advisors    |     1 |     0 |
| Musicians         |     1 |     1 |
| Plumbers          |     1 |     0 |
| Social Advisors   |     0 |     2 |
| Software Engineer |     2 |     0 |
+-------------------+-------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks what if I don't want the jobs with no Posts or Users to appear?

Comment: @giannosfor : Just change the first LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN. I add that output to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.I meant jobs with no Posts and no Users.In this example without the 'Structular Engineer'.

Comment: I added a WHERE clause to the query and updated my answer

Comment: You are just great!

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're after (or at least enough to set you on the right track):

```
SELECT occuDscr job, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN pstOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Posts', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN usrOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Users'
FROM  occupation_field
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
      users ON usrOccuId = occuId
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
      job_post ON pstOccuId = occuId
GROUP BY job
HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN pstOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
     OR SUM(CASE WHEN usrOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```

`occupation_field LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON usrOccuId = occuId`
 is essentially saying "give me all rows from `occupation_field`, and if `users` doesn't have a matching row for this `occuId` then fill it in with `NULL` values". See also the wikipedia article on [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_join#Outer_joins).

After that, we treat `NULL` values as 0 in the `CASE` statement, `SUM` it all and we're done.

Edit By @RolandoMySQLDBA 2012-01-11 11:42 EDT

Hey Simon. I ran your query against the dataset I made.

```
mysql> SELECT occuDscr job,
    ->        SUM(CASE WHEN pstOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Posts',
    ->        SUM(CASE WHEN usrOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Users'
    -> FROM  occupation_field
    ->           LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ->       users ON usrOccuId = occuId
    ->           LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ->       job_post ON pstOccuId = occuId
    -> GROUP BY job
    -> ;
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| job                 | Posts | Users |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| Economics           |     2 |     0 |
| Legal Advisors      |     1 |     0 |
| Musicians           |     1 |     1 |
| Plumbers            |     1 |     0 |
| Social Advisors     |     0 |     2 |
| Software Engineer   |     2 |     0 |
| Structural Engineer |     0 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Your query works as published. +1 !!!

Comment: I liked the way you applied the query,do you know an alternative way to appear only the jobs with at least one user or post? Meaning without "Structular Engineer" in this database. @RolandoMySQLDBA already gave me a correct answer.

Comment: as the last line, add `HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN pstOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR SUM(CASE WHEN usrOccuId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)`. That should filter out jobs where both the posts and users are zero.

Comment: Thanks men that's great.Can you post the whole query to your original answer.

Comment: Edited original answer to put the full query in, although I didn't change Rolando's section.

Comment: You are great..